# Finger segmentation using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Given a hand image with fingers spread, I can easily extract individual fingers by binarizing the input image and then extracting the largest connected components. e-g

[image] [image]

But I don't know how to achieve the same when fingers are closed, because when the fingers are closed I end up with one large connected component covering all the fingers. e-g

[image] [image]

I need to separate the fingers. Any suggestions, how to get this done or is it possible using opencv?

Comment: Maybe compute the convexity defects of the hand's convex hull. See: https://theailearner.com/tag/cv2-convexitydefects/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking into currently. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Acknowledge that it is impossible to achieve this without knowing the shape of fingers and the way they are arranged in a hand. A method is to find the leftmost and rightmost sides, position and direction, from that estimate the positions of the finger axis, and find the tips by traveling along them.  You can also look for spaces between the fingers, and adjust the axis positions accordingly.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan you can mask out the fingers inthe second image and then perform Canny edge detection or difference of Gaussians